# No response was received when the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission was requested

Tags: java

There is no response when I request the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission on some android devices, and there is no storage permission option in the device's setting application permission interface. Why

I want to be able to have a selection box feedback when requesting storage permissions